# Running multiple testsuites of single soapUi project in maven

Tags: maven, soapui, pom.xml, test-suite

I want to run multiple test suites from my project with in a single execution of maven. Somehow multiple run is not successful.

If I add two executions with the same test goal as below, each test suite is running as individually.

```
<executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                        <testSuite>SOAPTests1</testSuite>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectFile>soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                        <testSuite>SOAPTests2</testSuite>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

But I would like to run in a single execution or in a better way than the above as I have lot of different test suites to run and if I all all my test suites as above, that will just make my file look long.

I want my pom.xml look something like this:

```
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
        </goals>
    <configuration>
        <projectFile>LocalAdapa-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
        <testSuite>SOAPTests1</testSuite>
        <testSuite>SOAPTests2</testSuite>
        <testSuite>SOAPTests3</testSuite>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: You would like to execute the project itself to make it more simple?

Comment: Yes, correct. As mentioned above, I can do that as two executions, but would like to know if there is any other better way

Comment: What if you remove all the `testSuite` elements?

Comment: If I remove all the testSuite elements, all the tests run in alphabetical order of the testSuite names. This is where I need a solution to run all the testSuites in a proper order

Comment: The thumb rule I follow is each test case should be independent and so as the test suites, should not have dependency on the order of the execution. Any reason for the order?

Answer (score 0):

You can find some examples here [multiple Test Suites or Test Cases when executing tests from Maven](https://smartbear-cc.force.com/portal/KbArticleViewer?name=How-to-run-multiple-Test-Suites-or-Test-Cases-when-executing-tests-from-Maven&sp=all)